# VBA unexpetcted end of sub error

Tags: excel, vba, function

I found the following VBA code to sum coloured cells, however I get an unexpected end of statement error in the penultimate line:

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, SumRange As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim ICol As Integer
    Dim TCell As Range
    ICol = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each TCell In SumRange
        If ICol = TCell.Interior.ColorIndex Then
            SumByColor = SumByColor + TCell.Value
        End If
    Next TCell
End Function

Sub Count_red()
 =SumByColor(AC4,J2:AK1725)
End Sub
```

Edit: I adjusted the last bit according to your suggestions

`Sub Count_red()
 Function Count_red() As Double
    Count_red = SumByColor([AC4], [J2:A1725])
End Function
End Sub`

The new error message when I try to run the code: "Ambiguous name detected: Count_red()"

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Count_red()
 =SumByColor(AC4,J2:AK1725)
End Sub
```

Is an assignment to nothing.

Based on the names, I am guessing it is supposed to be

```
Function Count_red()
    Count_red=SumByColor([AC4],[J2:AK1725])
End Function
```

Comment: I think we're getting closer here. :) I pasted your code into the one above. However, I got a new error, saying "Expected: List separator or )". When I delete the range, only leaving J2 instead on J2:AK1725, he doesn't seem to have a problem anymore. However I need him to search a range..

Comment: `SumByColor("AC4","J2:AK1725")` or pass an explicit `Range` object using the current context of your Excel application within the script.

Comment: @MattPerry `Range("AC4"), Range("J2:AK1725")` since the sub is expecting a range object not address :)

Comment: @ykjk also, as you're modifying your code based on suggestions here, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16106396) your question so that it includes the code you're currently attempting to use, otherwise it is hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: I tried `SumByColor(Range("AC4"),Range("J2:A1725"))` as well as `SumByColor([AC4],[J2:AK1725])` both seem to work fine, but the error message "Ambiguous name detected: Count_red()" pops up, when I try to run the Makro.

Comment: @ykjk : Take out `Sub Count_red()` & `End Sub` since you're defining a `Function`- not a `Sub`.  The ambiguity in names comes from your attempt in defining a `Sub` & `Function` under the same name.